# VMware Workstation 15 Copy/Paste from Windows 7 Guest to Manjaro Linux Host is not working

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

When I try to Copy/Paste from a Windows 7 guest OS to the Manjaro Linux Host OS, I get the following error:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGg6c.png)

I then searched for that directory in the file system of the Host OS, I found it elsewhere, see the Screenshot to understand:
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmRN3.png)

Apparently, VMware Workstation is not pasting from the correct paths.

Is there any configuration to make VMware Workstation Copy/Paste to the correct paths?

What are your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably not the answer you're looking for (I know because it's gotten me frustrated as well), but a workaround to this is to use Shared Folders. In Workstation go to VM > Settings > Options tab > And in Folder Sharing switch to Always Enabled or whichever option you want. Map as a network drive in Windows guests can be left unchecked because it will automatically show your shared folder in Windows Explorer via Network. Then, click Add > Give the shared folder a name and then browse and select the directory you want to share (the one that you want to copy and paste in). Click OK and then Save. Then copying and pasting to the shared folder should work. The only reason I know about this is because I asked about it in IRC and someone gave me this suggestion. Currently, only copy and paste to the guest is working. And Workstation > Edit > Copy is grayed out.

One thing to keep in mind is that Workstation is not officially supported on Arch/Manjaro systems because of their rolling release update system. It's only officially supported on Ubuntu, Windows, and macOS. and the company that makes VMware doesn't seem to care about unsupported OSs. I don't expect this issue to be resolved for a little while until someone fixes it, and I don't even know what's causing it.

Comment: I already did this workaround solution you suggested before I post here seeking for a real solution. I just wanted to know if there is a real solution (a patch or something else). Thank you anyway.